# How do I add white space to a div but at the same time keep the words in the div?

Tags: html, css

How can I add words to a div that haves white space capabilities but at the same time it doesn't leak out of the div?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style> 
p.test {
    width: 11em; 
    border: 1px solid #000000;
    word-wrap: break-word;
    white-space: pre;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<p class="test">     This paragraph      contains a very long word: thisisaveryveryveryveryveryverylongword. The long word will break and wrap to the next line.</p>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use overflow-x css property. Setting it to scroll makes it scrollable. You can use hidden to make it not appear when it overflows.

**edit:** overflow-x:auto applies scrollbar only as necessary suggested by @Commercial Suicide.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style> 
p.test {
    border: 1px solid #000000;
    word-wrap: break-word;
    white-space: pre;
    overflow-x:auto;
    width:auto;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<p class="test">     This paragraph      contains a very long word: thisisaveryveryveryveryveryverylongword. The long word will break and wrap to the next line.</p>

</body>
</html>
```

**hidden version:**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style> 
p.test {
    width: auto; 
    border: 1px solid #000000;
    word-wrap: break-word;
    white-space: pre;
    overflow-x:hidden;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<p class="test">     This paragraph      contains a very long word: thisisaveryveryveryveryveryverylongword. The long word will break and wrap to the next line.</p>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Good solution, but I recommend to use `overflow-x: auto;`, so the scrollbar will be applied only when needed.

Comment: Thanks for your response but I don't want to rely on a scroll bar i'm making a chat system and I want to keep words in the div but at the same time they can add white space  with out being push out of a div.

Comment: If I have to change my code to be able to do that I will do that.

Comment: @Johnson If i understand you correct then you may want to use width:auto; instead of a set size of 11em. I updated the first example to do that.

Comment: Never mind I figure it out this is what help me to keep the words in the div but at the same time allow white space what this CSS command white-space: pre-wrap;

Comment: Here's the link if any one need help with this. https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/w/whitespace/

Answer (score 0):

If your concern is to have spaces between words that are longer than one space (that's one way to understand your question IMO), you can simply use standard (i.e. default) CSS settings and use `&nbsp;` entities for the ("white") spaces.

In addition, if you have words that are longer than the width of the container, you can use `word-break: break-all;` in separate spans around these words to which  you also apply `display: inline-block;` :

```css
.bw {
  display: inline-block;
  word-break: break-all;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <style>
    p.test {
      width: 11em;
      border: 1px solid #000000;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>

  <p class="test">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;This paragraph&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;contains a very long word: <span class="bw">thisisaveryveryveryveryveryverylongword.</span> The long word will break and wrap to the next line.</p>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Never mind I figure it out this is what help me to keep the words in the div but at the same time allow white space, with this CSS command call white-space: pre-wrap;

Here's the link if any one need help with this. https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/w/whitespace

Answer (score 0):

your css should be something like this:

```
p.test {
    border: 1px solid #000000;
    word-wrap: break-word;
    white-space: pre;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
```